# Forming a new basis from the elements of a subspace plus elements of a given basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Given are a basis A of a vector space V, and a basis B of a subspace of V. Is it always possible to form a basis of V by adding elements of A to B?

I'm assuming the answer is yes and that it should be a trivial matter to prove that it is.

Comment: There exists some element of $A$ that does not lie in the span of $B$ (why?). Append it to $B$  to increase the dimension of the span of $B$. You can continue this process until $B$ spans $V$.

Comment: Thanks, but it is the "why" bit that is puzzling me. Does the following make sense?

If all the elements of A are in the span of B then they are all linear combinations of the elements of B, making B a basis of V, i.e. the subspace is an improper subspace.

If there is an element of A that it is not in the span of B, then it is linearly independent of the elements of B and can be added to B form a new subspace C of dimension 1  greater than that of B. Then, if there is an element of A not in the span of C it can be added to C, etc.

Comment: That looks good to me

Comment: @DL1 your reasoning is correct in case of finite dimensional vector space. If the vector space $V$ has a countable basis you have to be more careful building your base from $B$, but it is still possible doing it inductively. If the dimension of $V$ is uncountable you can build your base with Zorn Lemma, or probably with transfinite induction.

Comment: @Andrea S. Thank you. It is primarily finite-dimensional spaces I am interested in.